# android onmouseup, onmousedown, onmousemove, oncontextmenu, onchange

Tags: android

Is it possible to execute onmouseup, onmousedown, onmousemove, oncontextmenu, onchange in android webview? I have tired using touchstart, touchend, and touchmove to replace onmouseup, onmousedown, and onmousemove respectively, but it doesn't work. And I cannot find any replacement of onchange and oncontextmenu.

Comment: I assume this is Javascript?  What browser are you trying it in-  there's more than one, and they may have different answers.

Comment: Yes that is Javascript, I am just using an android webview to display the HTML5, so I don't really know what browser it is.

Comment: Telling us its a webview is fine, that is the browser.  What we needed to know was were you talking about that, chrome, firefox, or a dozen others.

Comment: I use `webview.setWebViewClient`

Comment: I use an activity to hold the webview, it won't pop up a new browser, so I think it is default browser of android?